# Xcode 8.3.3 lost connection to iPhone 7 plus

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

This is frustrating, I recently got an iPhone 7 plus to use as a test device. Somehow, my Xcode always loose connection to it as soon as 
 I connect it to my Mac. Restarting my Mac will solve it.

Xcode version: 8.3.3

iOS version: 10.3.3

Luckily, I have another iPhone 6s for testing, which works fine. The iOS version is also 10.3.3. I don't want to use this one as a test device because it's my personal phone, messages and phone calls would interrupt my development.

Thanks in advance for any help : )

Comment: Make sure you are not using a dodgy cable. Also the lightning port on the iPhones sometimes gets dirty with dirt from the pockets. Cleaning it gently with a toothpick or similar might make the cable connections a bit more stable. Also make sure that you are not using a dodgy USB hub

Comment: The USB cable and port are both fine, I use it to connect my 6s and it works fine. But the 7plus sometimes looses connection to my Mac, and this continues to happen every time I re-connect it, until I restart my Mac, then everything's fine. I think this may be a bug in Xcode, and hopefully there's some one  who faced the same problem.

Comment: I would suggest in that case taking it back to Apple as it might be faulty. I got a 7 Plus and a 7 and both work fine for debugging

Comment: There were similar questions on Stack Overflow before, people usually had issues where their devices kept disconnecting from Xcode while running the app. The problem was that they used way to large images in the app and they ran out of memory on the device. It's a long shot, 'cause in theory iPhone 7 should work a lot better than 6s but I guess you can check that as well.